# Where can I see the Olympic Flame?

Tags: olympics

Before Olympic Games, the Olympic Flame is brought to the host city by a torch relay. Then, during the Olympic Games, the Olympic Flame is burning in the Olympic Cauldron located in or close to the stadium. However, I heard that the Olympic Flame is also burning during Olympia and will never be extinguished.

So I'm looking for the place where I can see the Olympic Flame during Olympiad. I guess it could be located in Greece, the place of the first Olympics?

Comment: Do you mean olympiad?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Wikipedia, the [olympic flame](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olympic_Flame) is ignited at Olympia, Greece, from the action of the Sun. No [eternal flame](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_flame) seems to exist at this site.

Comment: Wikipedia also says: "According to legend, the torch's flame has been kept burning ever since the first Olympics."

Comment: Yes. Not only it says "according to the legend" but also mentions that sentence as [dubious - discuss]. I didn't success in obtaining facts about it.